# "Cannot resolve method 'fromJson'

Tags: android, gson, google-play-services, fromjson

I was trying to read the information of a Json file but there is an error that say me:

```
Cannot resolve method 'fromJson(android.util.JsonReader, java.lang.Class<com.proyecto.matriculas.model.Matricula>)'
```

I have other classes where i get the information of the file and where i did the conexion with the server, in which is the json file , and the only problem is here, in this class.

**The class where i try it is:**

```
public class GsonMatriculaParser {
    public List leerFlujoJson(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        List<Matricula> matriculas = new ArrayList<>();

        reader.beginArray();

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            Matricula matricula = (Matricula) gson.fromJson(reader, Matricula.class);
            matriculas.add(matricula);
        }


        reader.endArray();
        reader.close();
        return matriculas;
    }
}
```

**And the error is in**   `gson.fromJson(reader, Matricula.class);`

I'm using `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'` as my `gson` depencency in my `build.gradle`.

**Class Matricula:**

```
public class Matricula {

private Integer N_Registro;
    private String Infraccion;
    private String Fecha_Infraccion;
    private String N_Matricula;
    private Integer IDPropietariosFK;


    public Matricula(Integer N_Registro,  String Infraccion, String Fecha_Infraccion, String N_Matricula, Integer IDPropietariosFK) {
        this.N_Registro = N_Registro;
        this.Infraccion = Infraccion;
        this.Fecha_Infraccion = Fecha_Infraccion;
        this.N_Matricula = N_Matricula;
        this.IDPropietariosFK = IDPropietariosFK;
    }

    public Integer getN_Registro() {
        return N_Registro;
    }

    public void setN_Registro(Integer N_Registro) {
        this.N_Registro = N_Registro;
    }

    public String getInfraccion() {
        return Infraccion;
    }

    public void setInfraccion(String Infraccion) {
        this.Infraccion = Infraccion;
    }

    public String getFecha_Infraccion() {
        return Fecha_Infraccion;
    }

    public void setFecha_Infraccion(String Fecha_Infraccion) { this.Fecha_Infraccion = Fecha_Infraccion; }

    public String getN_Matricula() {
        return N_Matricula;
    }

    public void setN_Matricula(String N_Matricula) {
        this.N_Matricula = N_Matricula;
    }

    public Integer getIDPropietariosFK() {
        return IDPropietariosFK;
    }

    public void setIDPropietariosFK(Integer IDPropietariosFK) { this.IDPropietariosFK = IDPropietariosFK; }

}
```

I don't know if the problem is with the dependecy or the problem is in the code in one of my classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong `JsonReader`:

- You are using `android.util.JsonReader`
- The parameter is `com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader`

Comment: True, I did the import bad... Thanks!!